# How can I find the maximal value of this?

Tags: maximum

I already plot the image of the function S:

```
(* structural entropy for N=3 *)
S[p1_, p2_] := (
S1 = -(p1*Log[p1] + p2*Log[p2] + (1 - p1 - p2) Log[(1 - p1 - p2)]);
S2 = 1 - (p1^2 + p2^2 + (1 - p1 - p2)^2);
Sstr = S1 - S2
)
Plot3D[S[p1, p2], {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I use the code

```
MaxValue[{S[p1, p2], 0 <= p1 <= 1, 0 <= p2 <= 1}, {p1, p2}]
```

but I can't get the maximum value. The output can give the answer.

Comment: Look at "S1" If p1+p2==1,  "S1" is not defined. If p1+p2>1, "S1" is complex. Therefore, there is no max. for 0<= {p1,p2}<=1

Comment: $p1+p2+p3=1$,and $p1,p2,p3\in [0,1]$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[{Grad[S[p1, p2], {p1, p2}] == 0, 0 < p1 <= 1, 0 < p2 <= 1,
    1 - p1 - p2 > 0}, {p1, p2}]
S[p1, p2] /. sol[[1]]
% // N
hessian = D[S[p1, p2], {{p1, p2}, 2}] /. sol[[1]]
NegativeDefiniteMatrixQ[hessian]
```

> `{p1 -> 1/3, p2 -> 1/3}`

> `-(2/3) + Log[3]`

> `0.431946`

> `True`

The same as

```
NMaximize[{S[p1,p2], 
  0 < p1 <= 1, 0 < p2 <= 1, 1 - p1 - p2 > 0}, {p1, p2}]
```

> `{0.431946, {p1 -> 0.333197, p2 -> 0.333294}}`

Comment: Wait a minute, can I get the exact solution? Or 0.431946 is the exact solution?